# Restart Android Studio

Tags: android

How to restart Android Studio to overcome Gradle project refresh failed error-

Failed to find target with hash string 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23' in: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Comment: And your configs are like what?

Comment: Android Studio 2.3.2

Answer (score 5):

**open `SDK Manager` to confirm you have sdk of `Google APIs:23`, if you have then follow these instruction :**

```
Go to File>Invalidate Caches/Restart..
```

it will restart your android studio and auto resolve your Gradle problem.

Comment: I tried updating to API 23 and clicked Go to File>Invalidate Caches/Restart.. but still have the same error - Gradle Sync failed - Failed to find target with hash string 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23' in: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Comment: are you sure you have API's 23 SDK and build tools  23.x.x versions?

Comment: Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)  23 3 Installed

Comment: Gradle build finished in 11s 420ms but not able to run the app - Available virtual device - Nexus 5 API 23 x86, Nexus 6 API 23 - Your CPU doesnt support VT-x - Dont know how to create suitable new virtual device

Comment: Use GenyMotion for Virtual Device its very fast compare to AVD.

Comment: ok thnx Aniruddh but before that would like to learn the basics for emulators

Answer (score 5):

[image]

You can select the option from file menu - invalidate caches/ restart

Answer (score 0):

Try `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and Restart`, worked for me.

If Still there is error open the `Android SDK Manager` and install the build tools for for all 23.x.x versions.