# IDE Fatal Errors

Tags: android-studio

I am new to Android Development and I was doing this exercise where you create a basic Activity (Android 4.4 kitkat) and remove the TextView and add a ListView in a CoordinatorLayout and program the Floating action Button in such a way that Each time you click it, it adds current time date/month/year in the list. The IDE is not showing any syntax errors and everything seems fine also I am running the latest version of Android Studio (3.3.1) but when I run it on my onePlus (Android 8) the app is simply not opening (ABC has stopped -open app again), I've tried cleaning /rebuilding.

But however when I click on the bottom right button on my IDE where it says internal IDE error occurred and after clicking it it shows something Quite Overwhelming for me:

```
C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-28/data/annotations.zip!/android/telephony/euicc/annotations.xml

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 22; columnNumber: 12; Content is not allowed in trailing section.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$TrailingMiscDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.BaseExternalAnnotationsManager.getDataFromFile(BaseExternalAnnotationsManager.java:158)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.BaseExternalAnnotationsManager.doCollect(BaseExternalAnnotationsManager.java:193)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.BaseExternalAnnotationsManager.collectExternalAnnotations(BaseExternalAnnotationsManager.java:126)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.BaseExternalAnnotationsManager.findExternalAnnotation(BaseExternalAnnotationsManager.java:88)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.AnnotationUtil.lambda$null$0(AnnotationUtil.java:103)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.ConcurrentFactoryMap$3.create(ConcurrentFactoryMap.java:212)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.ConcurrentFactoryMap.get(ConcurrentFactoryMap.java:59)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.AnnotationUtil.findNonCodeAnnotation(AnnotationUtil.java:121)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.AnnotationUtil.findAnnotation(AnnotationUtil.java:76)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.AnnotationUtil.findAnnotation(AnnotationUtil.java:55)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.AnnotationUtil.findAnnotation(AnnotationUtil.java:48)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiImplUtil.isDeprecatedByAnnotation(PsiImplUtil.java:457)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsClassImpl.isDeprecated(ClsClassImpl.java:315)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.lookup.impl.JavaElementLookupRenderer.isDeprecated(JavaElementLookupRenderer.java:72)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.lookup.impl.JavaElementLookupRenderer.isToStrikeout(JavaElementLookupRenderer.java:68)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.JavaPsiClassReferenceElement.renderClassItem(JavaPsiClassReferenceElement.java:144)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.lookup.PsiTypeLookupItem.renderElement(PsiTypeLookupItem.java:256)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.lookup.LookupElementDecorator.renderElement(LookupElementDecorator.java:83)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.lookup.LookupElementDecorator.renderElement(LookupElementDecorator.java:83)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.lookup.impl.LookupImpl.renderItemApproximately(LookupImpl.java:458)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.lookup.impl.LookupImpl.addItem(LookupImpl.java:247)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionProgressIndicator.addItemToLookup(CompletionProgressIndicator.java:438)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionProgressIndicator.addItem(CompletionProgressIndicator.java:429)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.AsyncCompletion$1.lambda$null$0(CompletionThreading.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1164)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.AsyncCompletion.tryReadOrCancel(CompletionThreading.java:181)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.AsyncCompletion$1.lambda$consume$1(CompletionThreading.java:157)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.AsyncCompletion$1WeighItems.run(CompletionThreading.java:125)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.AsyncCompletion.lambda$null$0(CompletionThreading.java:108)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.AsyncCompletion.lambda$startThread$1(CompletionThreading.java:104)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: theres something wrong with one of your XML files. Could you paste the one thats giving you an error

Comment: i dont see any error signs but if you see the first line of error .. it says C:/ blah blah ..annotations.xml

Comment: `annotations.xml` seems to be corrupted or have data added to the end of it or something. If that's an IDE controlled file, an update may have been fubared or something. Take a look at the file to see if there's something lingering at the end.

Comment: have you tried to [invalidate caches and restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44199791/restart-android-studio)? This is another way to "refresh" your project in addition to Clean/rebuild

Comment: user3170251 ..i just did ..it shows "cant bind to  local 8602 for debugger" in the event log  after i tried to run it again

Comment: @Carcigenicate i dont see anything fishy . and i cant paste the data here . but the file is quite small though (10lines)