# Can't even run an empty project in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

when I simply create an android project and run it, it throws the error as the follows

```
android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.***"
        minSdk 19
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

> class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

I use java version 11 and jdk version 16
thanks in advance...

Comment: is your application id actually ```applicationId "com.***"``` of have you simply hidden it here?

Comment: simply hidden bro

Comment: can you perform a restart as show here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44199791/restart-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

Note that if your using Java 11

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

should be

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
```

It's best to use Android Studio provided JRE. Only Android Studio **versions >= 2020.3.1** provide Java 11 support.